# Running application built with CATIA API without related license

Tags: c#, dll, catia

Here is current situation, I as developer have to develop a WPF application using APIs exposed by CATIA V5 for end user to do some automation work in CAITA V5 environment. I have used a reference library that end user does not have. This causes an issue that by end user side the application crashes.

I am thinking of a solution but not sure if it works. By launching the application, it will be checked if user has such library file in the local machine. If not, the dll file will be copied to certain path and user has to relaunch CATIA, so that the dll file will also be loaded.

Is it a possible solution? If so, where should I put the dll file? Could someone help me with the issue? Thank you.

Comment: What is the dll? Why don't you add the dll to your project? After building, you should have the dll created in your /bin folder.